# Extracting enum type from propertyType

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I have the below scenario

```
public class TestData
{
     public TestEnum EnumTestData{get;set;}
}

public Enum TestEnum
{
     Test1,Test2,Test3 
}
```

I have another class which traverse through my TestData class for all properties. Depending on the property type it will generate random data for it. Now when my propertyType is Enum type, How can I know which type of enum it is and how to get either Test1, Test2 or Test3 as my output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a list of all properties using the [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx) method:

```
var targetType = typeof(TestData);
var properties = targetType.GetProperties();
```

Then check whether it's an `Enum` type by checking the [`PropertyInfo.PropertyType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx) and [`Type.IsEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum.aspx) properties:

```
foreach(var prop in properties)
{
    if (prop.PropertyType.IsEnum)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally get a random value using the [`Enum.GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) method:

```
var random = new Random();
...

var values = Enum.GetValues(prop.PropertyType);
var randomValue = ((IList)values)[random.Next(values.Length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just `.ToString()` the `EnumTestData` property, like this:

```
var test = new TestData();
test.EnumTestData = TestEnum.Test1;

var dummy = test.EnumTestData.ToString();
```

Note: `dummy` will be `"Test1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but this is how you would compare and get the string value of an enum:

```
var td = new TestData();
// compare
if (td.EnumTestData == TestEnum.Test1)
{
    // Will output "Test1"
    Console.WriteLine(td.EnumTestData.ToString());
}
```

Also, I'm sure it's just a typo but it's `enum` not `Enum`:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
     Test1,Test2,Test3 
}
```